# REACTION INIT : Node modules were not successfully installed

Tags: node.js, npm, permissions, node-modules, sudo

I got permission errors when I try to create a reaction project :

```
➜  myproject sudo npm install npm@latest -g
[sudo] Mot de passe de julien : 
/usr/local/bin/npx -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
/usr/local/bin/npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
+ npm@6.3.0
added 283 packages, removed 363 packages and updated 41 packages in 12.239s


➜  myproject npm -v
6.3.0


➜  myproject sudo npm install -g reaction-cli
npm WARN deprecated command-exists@1.2.2: Potential security vulnerability fixed in v.1.2.4
/usr/local/bin/reaction -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/reaction-cli/dist/main.js
/usr/local/bin/rc -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/reaction-cli/dist/main.js
+ reaction-cli@0.29.0
updated 2 packages in 17.817s

➜  myproject sudo reaction init

Cloning the master branch of Reaction from Github...

Clonage dans 'reaction'...
remote: Counting objects: 131122, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (50/50), done.
remote: Total 131122 (delta 18), reused 40 (delta 12), pack-reused 131059
Réception d'objets: 100% (131122/131122), 48.39 MiB | 421.00 KiB/s, fait.
Résolution des deltas: 100% (74545/74545), fait.

Installing NPM packages...

npm ERR! write after end

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/julien/.npm/_logs/2018-08-02T09_05_18_750Z-debug.log

Error: Node modules were not successfully installed. Exiting.
```

Notice that I installed Ubuntu on an USB hdd few days ago. I installed nvm yesterday (npm-v = 6.3.0).

I suppose it's a permission issue but I'm new on Linux os, have you got an advice ?

Answer (score 0):

I used npm i -g npm@5.6.0 to downgrade npm version (apparently other versions fail to extract large projects).
more info on [npm github](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19989)